# Test client doesn't throw expected 404 error

Tags: django

I'm facing a weird error in which a Django test I wrote to test a view's response isn't giving me the expected behavior.

Consider the following model for a simple blogging application:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    """Represents a Post in the blogging system."""

    # is the post published or in draft stage?
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('draft', 'Draft'), 
        ('published', 'Published'),
        ('deleted', 'Deleted'),
    )

    # the default mode for posts
    DRAFT = STATUS_CHOICES[0][0]

    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    text = models.TextField(null=True)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    date_published = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=DRAFT)

    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', null=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey('Author', null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-date_published',)

    @property
    def truncated_text(self):
        if len(self.text) > 200:
                return '{} . . .'.format(self.text[0:300])
        else:
                return self.text 

    def publish(self):
        self.date_published = timezone.now()
        self.status = 'published'
        self.save()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Set slug only on new posts
        if not self.id:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)

        self.last_modified = timezone.now()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Here's the view (you can see that I'm insisting on getting published posts only):

```
def post_view(request, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug, status='published')
    return render(request, 'blog/single_post.html', {'post': post})
```

Here's the URL entry:

```
url(r'^blog/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', blog_view.post_view, name='single_post'),
```

And finally, here's the test:

```
class TestBlogViews(TestCase):
    """Class to test the views of our blog app"""

    def setUp(self):
        """Make sure we have an environment in which to render the templates"""

        # An author
        self.author = Author()
        self.author.name = 'Ankush'
        self.author.short_name = 'ank'
        self.author.save()

        # A category
        self.cat = Category()
        self.cat.name = 'Programming'
        self.cat.save()

        # A post
        self.post = Post()
        self.post.title = 'Dummy title'
        self.post.text = 'Dummy text that does nuffin'
        self.post.author = self.author
        self.post.category = self.cat

        setup_test_environment()
        self.client = Client()

    def test_unpublished_post_raises_404(self):
        self.post.save()
        response = self.client.get(reverse('single_post', args=('dummy-title',)))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 404)
```

So basically, my test fails because I'm getting `200 != 404`. I also ran the `Post` api from shell, and got a `DoesNotExist` when looking for `status = 'published'` on a post that only had the `save()` method called. I also printed the `response.content` in my test, and it contains the custom 404 template content. Why isn't it throwing 404 when the object clearly doesn't exist? Something wrong with `get_object_or_404()`?

P.S. Please let me know if you need more snippets of code.

Comment: What test database are you using? Can you make sure that the database is indeed clean without previous data in there that somehow confuses the situation?

Comment: @ShangWang Well, I'm relying on the test database Django creates (usong MariaDB 10.1, by the way). Doesn't Django destroy and rebuild things every time?

Comment: @ShangWang Okay I was able to make some improvement. I actually had to create a new `Client()` for every method. This way, I now get the custom 404 page content, but the response code is still `200`. Funny! :-|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right, I was able to figure it out. Turns out my custom 404 view was screwed up:

It was:

```
def not_found(request):
    return render(request, 'ankblog/not_found.html')
```

So naturally the status code was `200`. It got fixed by changing it to `return render(request, 'ankblog/not_found.html', status=404)`.

I do find it funny, though. I would've thought that the custom 404 would have raised a 404 error automatically.